# Python not detecting if a string is equal to an element in a list even though its the same

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
List = [["in the basement", "im Untergeschoss"], ["| have been living ... (for four years).", "Ich wohne (seit vier Jahren) ..."], ["semi-detached house", "die Doppelhaushalfte"], ["on the ground floor", "im Erdgeschoss"], ["on the outskirts / in the suburbs", "am Stadtrand"], ["parking space", "om NUicesicllelt-iv4"]]


# Path of tesseract executable
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'



cap = ImageGrab.grab(bbox =(x1, y1, x2, y2))

# Converted the image to monochrome for it to be easily read
tesstr = pytesseract.image_to_string(cv2.cvtColor(nm.array(cap), cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY), lang ='eng')


for i in range(0, len(List)):
    
    print(str(List[i][0]))
    print(str(List[i][1]))
    print(str(tesstr))
          
    if tesstr == List[i][0]:
        print("works")
        pyautogui.click(x1, (y1 + 50))
        print(tesstr)
        
    if tesstr == List[i][1]:
        print("works")
        pyautogui.click(x1, (y1 + 50))
        print(tesstr)
```

The problem is, when the List[i][0] is equal to the tesstr, it is not recognised and never prints("works"). I have printed them all off seperately to see if they are equal and from what I can see they all are, at some point throughout times it prints it.

Comment: you probably have trailing whitespace or something. try replacing your prints with something like `print('|' + List[i][0] + '|'))` and `print('|' + tesstr +'|')`

Comment: that was the problem thank you I had to use the strip function to remove the whitespace